# Как отключить повторяющую библиотеку .Jar (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как отключить повторяющую (библиотеку метод или это класс ) поскольку сверху используется более новая версия.

Из за того ,что появилась ошибка java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: после перехода на Target api 29

Answer (score 0):

[image: Как скопировать путь до библиотеки]

Из Android Studio удалить jar файл напрямую будет проблематично. Для удаления Jar файла Вам необходимо:

1. Перейти в режим просмотра директорий "Packages".
2. Там в папке "Libraries" вам нужно найти нужную Вам директорию (Например, java.util.jar).
3. Правой кнопкой мыши кликнуть на нужную Вам директорию для удаления и в открывшемся меню выбрать "Copy Paths". Таким образом, вы скопируете путь до этой библиотеки.
4. После чего полученный путь вставьте в Ваш проводник файлов/менеджер файлов. Вполне возможно, что напрямую найти местоположение этой папки не получится, так как она завёрнута в Jar-архив, поэтому нужно будет укоротить полученный путь, пока не найдёте искомый jar-архив. В моём случае он называется rt.jar.
5. Удалить Jar-архив как обычный файл.

Comment: Я только не пойму почему эта библиотека находиться не в папке с моим приложением а в корневой папке Android Studio .  У  меня как и у вас  он называется rt.jar. Вы как весь rt.jar удалили или классы которые в нем есть. Просто может эта библиотека нужна  классы  повторяются  за этого , и ошибка java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

Comment: Я нашел   rt.jar по пути (C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib ) если удалить его  целиком  то Android studio не запускается от слова  совсем. А если удалить в  rt.jar  нужные мне методы тогда программа запускается с ошибкой и на этом все выключается .

Comment: Напишите если не сложно по какому пути  вы нашли rt.jar

Comment: @Yacow Да, всё верно. Эта библиотека находится именно по этому пути. Это не часть Вашего приложения, так как вы не подключали эту библиотеку через Gradle. Это часть Android фреймворка. Скорее всего стоит поискать другой способ избавления от этой ошибки, нежели удалние rt.jar. 
Когда я переходил на Target API 29 ничего удалять не пришлось